# Empty Field Validation for Editing Stored Record Not Working

Tags: edit

I have connected to my database to edit stored records and I’ve used a variable for the errors.

When I try to submit with empty fields it redirects and displays the changes have been saved message instead of displaying empty fields message

I’m sure there is something wrong with the structure of my loop and I am putting something in the wrong place?

```
<?php
//session_start();
// connect to the database
include('connect.php');
$message = $_GET['message'];
// check if the form has been submitted then process it
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// Get data from table
//set the id manually for test purposes
$id = "429";
$forename = $_POST['forename'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
// check for empty fields and display error message
if (empty($forename) &&!empty($surname) &&!empty($username) &&!empty ($password) &&!empty ($email))
{
$message = "Please enter data in all fields" ;
header("Location: edit.php?message=$message");
}
else
{
// save the data to the table
mysql_query("UPDATE registration SET forename='$forename', surname='$surname', username='$username', email='$email', password='$password' WHERE id='$id'")
or die(mysql_error()); 
}
// redirecr and display message
$message = "Your changes have been saved";
header("Location: edit.php?message=$message");
exit;
}
$id=429;// this line could have been $id=$_SESSION['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registration WHERE id=$id LIMIT 1")
or die(mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
// check that the 'id' matches up with a row in the databse
if($row)
{
// get data from the table
$forename = $row['forename'];
$surname = $row['surname'];
$username = $row['username'];
$email = $row['email'];
$password = $row['password'];
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/all.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/forms.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cantora+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Voltaire' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />

<title>Chocolate Review</title>
<meta name="Description" content="Chocolate Review" />
<meta name="Keywords" content="Chocolate Review" />

</head>

<body>


<div class="container">

<div id="navigation">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="dairymilk.php">Dairy Milk</a></li>
<li><a href="ferrerorocher.php">Ferrero Rocher</a></li>
<li><a href="kitkat.php">Kit Kat</a></li>
<li><a href="mars.php">Mars</a></li>
<li><a href="snickers.php">Snickers</a></li>
<li><a href="twix.php">Twix</a></li>
<li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
<li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="edit" id="editrecord">
<fieldset>
<legend><span class="headingreg">Edit Details</span></legend>

<div class="formreg">

<br style="clear:left;"/>
<label class="editlabel" for="forename">Forename</label><div><input type="text" id="forename" name="forename" class="insetedit" value="<?php echo $forename; ?>"/><br/></div>
<label class="editlabel" for="forename">Surname</label><div><input type="text" name="surname" class="insetedit" value="<?php echo $surname; ?>"/><br/></div>
<label class="editlabel" for="forename">Username</label><div><input type="text" name="username" class="insetedit" value="<?php echo $username; ?>"/><br/></div>
<label class="editlabel" for="forename">Password</label><div><input type="text" name="password" class="insetedit" value="<?php echo $password; ?>"/><br/></div>
<label class="editlabel" for="forename">email</label><div><input type="text" name="email" class="insetedit" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"/><br/></div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit2" value="submit">
</div>

<?php print $message; ?>

</fieldset>
</form>


<br style="clear:left;"/>
<br style="clear:left;"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  This

```
if (empty($forename) || empty($surname) || empty($username) || empty ($password) || empty ($email))
    {
    $message = "Please enter data in all fields" ;
    header("Location: edit.php?message=$message");
    }
```

Comment: Strange. If I have Smith for the surname and remove it and click submit, the field value (in this case Smith) defaults to the previous value which is better than saved empty records but still no error message.